# How can I dynamically size table columns to fit content, left justify, and keep a max width?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, css-tables, element-ui

I found tons of example that are close to what I'm looking for, but I need more control over the design of the table. In addition, I don't want text to wrap, and want to show ellipsis and allow the content to have a tooltip when hovered over to see it all.

This is a [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/) project and I was (or am depending on if I can get it to work) using [Element UI](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table)

So getting to the details. I want my table to look like this:

```
Header A    Header B                     Header C
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 100%
Apples      Bananas la la la la la la... A box of crackers and some super ri...
Oranges     Mr. Bean Is Cool             More chocolate milk
```

That example is `text-overflow: ellipsis`

Or like this:

```
Header A    Header B    Header C
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 100%
Apples      Bananas     A box of crackers and some super rich chocolate milk
Oranges     Mr. Bean    More chocolate milk
```

Or like this:

```
Header A    Header B                      Header C
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 100%
Apples      Bananas are not my favorite   A box of crackers and some super r...
Oranges     Mr. Bean                      More chocolate milk
```

Or like this:

```
Header A    Header B    Header C
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 100%
Apples      Bananas     Oranges
Running     Out         Of ideas to put in here
```

The point is to keep the fields left aligned and not responsively spread across. I've tried various layouts such as `table-layout: fixed` with and `width: auto` and honestly I've tried so many variations that I'm not sure which to share.

To make it more difficult, the table is generated dynamically from `json` and I don't know what columns I'll even have or their content. So here are some of the pseudo steps I've taken:

```
// Figure out how many actual columns are visible
let visibleColumns = _.filter(this.$refs.table.columns, c => {
  return c.label != null && c.label.length;
}).length;

// I'm doing this so I can just guess a good max width on a column
// Switch trimmed for brevity
let maxWidth;
switch (visibleColumns) {
  case 1:
    maxWidth = 1000;
    break;
  case 2:
    maxWidth = 700;
    break;      
  default:
    maxWidth = 200;
    break;
  }

// Loop over my dynamic columns and find the longest value from the data
_.each(cols, c => {
  const comparer = Math.max(...this.data.map(d => String(d[c.field]).length));
});

// I then print the alpha equivalent to the length of the longest field into a hidden
// div and get the width and compare it with the max width based on columns

// i.e. if maxWidth is less than the length of the column then use that, else the div width
```

Element UI has a minWidth and width prop, no max width. And they have a nice auto-tooltip feature. But trying to control the table has proven itself to be more difficult than it's worth, so I'll build my own table component. I've found that others have gone down this path with Element UI's table and ran into several annoyances.

To sum it up, I need to intelligently balance out the columns and handle the text-overflow, and show a tooltip on the item if it's partially hidden.

Here's a fiddle showing the very first problem I ran into with the overflow when I wanted that last column to stretch.

https://jsfiddle.net/xtrvygfq/

Comment: I don't think you can with <table />, but you can achieve that with flexbox. I guess my question to you would be: do you have to use table elements to layout your data?

Comment: I suppose not, as long as it looks like a table. Just tricky business trying to create an intelligent table that truncates properly.

Comment: Ok that's doable then. You would have to use flexbox so that they can automatically take up the extra spaces. The problem would be setting the widths for each column so that it looks like a table. Since you're looping over your data to get the information, you can find the longest value on each column and calculate the percentage of each and use that as the width of each column. Do you have a sample test data we can use? I can try to create a demo for you.

Comment: @DavidLiang I would love an example if you have something in mind. Just sample data in that fiddle I posted.

Comment: @DavidLiang here is a fiddle. I feel like I'm almost there. But I want the columns to only take up the necessary space, not spread out evenly, and the last column to stretch the remainder so the actual table is 100% width. https://jsfiddle.net/xshcwqa4/

Comment: I made a demo too: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/9tcj0dfp/169/. I am not sure if that's what you want though. My strategy is to use the average string length for each column, calculate its percentage and use that as the width.

Comment: Cool @DavidLiang. This looks pretty good. I think I can use a combination of both. Next step is to (with performance in mind) know which ones are truncated so I can show a tooltip. I've seen several examples but a little concerned about larger data sets. Maybe I should trigger the logic on hover.

Comment: I had kind of similar problems before. What I did was just to set a fixed length on the server, and anything that's longer than that would get truncated.

Comment: Having issues with this. I think I want to try to avoid the functions that set a width. Are you able to take my latest fiddle and make those widths auto instead of stretching @DavidLiang ?

Comment: With the flexbox approach, you would have to set widths to make the flexbox rows look like table rows.

Answer (score 0):

Css can solve your problem.

```
.cell-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
}
```

Your Html

```
<td v-for="h in colDefs">
    <div class="cell-overflow">{{d[h.field]}}</div>
</td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k2fh8b53/2/

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple. I don't want to set a fixed width and table layout needs to be auto so it doesn't spread across the width of the table. Please see my (possibly terrible) examples of table layout in question.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood the question

Comment: I updated my answer, would it help if something like this?

Comment: I've hit further complications using a table in general. Do you think you can please take this example and make it auto width on the columns but allow the last one to stretch so that it appears 100% width? I didn't anticipate this being so complex. https://jsfiddle.net/xshcwqa4/

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of scenario you were trying to make. If you know your content data length, you can roughly set the width length just like you did in on the first column. 
However, if your data is quite random, the previous answer that I post I guess is quite generic, and able to fit most of the data. 

1. https://jsfiddle.net/k2fh8b53/2/ 
2. https://jsfiddle.net/zm1a3xr8/1/